# Unwanted Scrolling to Top for Ios Devices CSS Grid

Tags: css, safari

I am having issues with the scrollbar in mobile safari with the card that I have created when you scroll down it automatically goes to the top. The scrollbar works perfectly in android and desktopas as shown in the link here https://www.besocialscene.com/new-sept-homepage?hs_preview=YhTtsyAc-13258353405 but on Ios it doesn't work well. see below.

The CSS is save in the Jfiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/cfpywmd6/`
   I have tried adding this style to the container but still it won't work

```
 max-height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.back .description ul {
  position: absolute;
}

.back .description ul .draw-border {
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
}
```